# Gettin information from JSON file for jPlayer Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jplayer, playlist

I'm making a music player for my site using jPlayer.

What I want is to have a JSON file hosted somewhere to store track title and file name. And by clicking different buttons to load different playlists.

### How do I load information from JSON files into my player?

---

Here is the JSON itself:

```
{"tracks":[
    {
        "title": "Some Track 1",
        "trackname": "Some_track_name_1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Some Track 2",
        "trackname": "Some_track_name_2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Some Track 3",
        "trackname": "Some_track_name_3"
    }
]}
```

Here is the idea for JS I have.

```
$.getJSON("path/to/playlist.json",
function(....){

//Get JSON data and generate a playlist
//Playlists are generated with:
    customPlaylist.add({
        title: title var,
        mp3: 'track path' + filename var + '.mp3' ,
    });   
});
```

And once the custom playlist is created it awaits to be set as default playlist called myPlaylist by jPlayer:

```
$("#Playlist_1").click(function() {
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([

       set the generated playlist "customPlaylist" as the 
       default playlist "myPlaylist" here....

    ]);
```

And this way I THINK I'll have multiple playlists so users can chose which one to play.

---

My knowlge of JS and JSON is limited so what I have are just rough ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right direction!

You only have to use the variable you are getting back. Tracks is an array, so you can loop through it with forEach;

```
$.getJSON("path/to/playlist.json",
    function(playlist){

//Get JSON data and generate a playlist
//Playlists are generated with:
        playlist.tracks.forEach(function(track){
            customPlaylist.add({
                title: track.title,
                mp3: 'track path' + track.trackname + '.mp3' ,
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I read alot about this but my knowledge is too limited to even know what array is. I knew i had to loop for each so i added tacks in the JSON.
Can you show me how to make the second part aswell?
To change the custom playlist to default one?

Comment: @RadoslavT. An array is a collection of data. You can walk through each item in that collection with forEach. In your case, a collection of tracks.